# Present Continuous and already

Tags: present-continuous

> The new model is already selling well, even though the advertising campaign just started.

I am wondering why *already* is used here. Does the word refer to one action that (has) happened before it, *started*? Plus, please someone explain the meaning of the whole sentence for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Present continuous is used because it describes a continuing activity in the present: *the model is selling* means that people are continuously buying the model.

*Already* is used to indicate that sales have reached this pace *now* and that *now* is earlier than this pace was expected. Ordinarily we expect an advertising campaign to take some time to generate sales; in this case, however, the model is selling quickly before the campaign has matured.

Answer (score -1):

The first part of the sentence is correct. There is a problem with the second part "even though the advertising campaign just started". Present perfect would be expected here: "even though the advertising campaign has just started".